# Git commits associated with two user names

Tags: git, github

I don't know why I ignored this thing for months, and I couldn't figure out why it was happening. So, in most of my repos, when I check the commit history, it shows commits with the same author name as mine but with a white space in between, like: **jamie smith** instead of **jamiesmith**.
And in some commits, there's the correct author name and there's **verified** written in green next to those commits.

I have seen another answer on this but I was not satisfied. I just want to somehow replace the wrong author name with the correct author name in all my repos.

- Can it be done at once?
- I've collaborated with three people on a project. So, can I safely change it?

Comment: The answer for the 2nd Q is "no, don't do it, it imposes too much troubles for your collaborators" so it doesn't matter if the answer for the 1st Q is "yes".

Comment: So, can I change my name for the other repos except the one with collaborators?

Comment: Yes. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/750172/7976758

Comment: would changing the author's name have some effect on the chart?
like the past contributions which were made from another author name would change to my original author name, and the chart be more green lol?

Comment: Depends on the script you use. Be careful and do not change names/emails that don't need to be changed.